# How to create a URL that links directly to open a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue where I'm attempting to use a URL to open a Modal in window B, by clicking on an image link in window A. The image itself is setup inside an anchor tag, such that `<a href="myserver.mydestinationB.com#myModal><img src='myImage'></a>` is in window A.

How can I get to window B AND open the modal only using the URL, if possible.

Code :

### Page A

```
<a href="http://www.x.com/#DesiredModalID">
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://google.com/image.png" width="1920" height="1080" alt="">
</a>
```

### Page B

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button id="modalclose" class="close" data-    dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>

<h4 class="modal-title" id="header-data">Modal Header</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<p id="modal-text">Some text in the modal.</p>

<div id="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<h5 id="footer-data" style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;float:left;">Test Data</h5>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closetwo" type="button">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code? Give us a [mcve] of what you have so far please.

Comment: I actually worked it out with a simple hackaround. I added a the following function to the destination page.

`window.onload = function(){
  // alert(window.location.hash)
  if (window.location.hash == "#ICDVideo")
  {
   $('#ICDVideo').click();
  }
 }`

Comment: If you are toggling modal, you could use `$('#modalId').modal('toggle') `

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="myimage" src='myImage'>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myimage").click(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    })

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="myserver.mydestinationB.com?mymodal=open>


--- On Page B you add script ---

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var mymodal = $_GET('mymodal');

if(mymodal != null){
        $("#myModal").modal();
}

})

function $_GET(param) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( location.hash, '' ).replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );

    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}

</script>
```